# absolute path in subdomain

Tags: php, url, path, relative-path, absolute

I have made an application (php, css, js) with absolute path like

```
<img src="/images/example.jpg" alt=""/>
```

and others for including resources (js, css, etc.)

The application was initially destinated to be hosted on a server like http://domain.com
Now I need to host the site in a subfolder http://domain.com/2013/

How can I update my application and make it accessible in the new subfolder without update all the paths.

Maybe with .htaccess ?

Comment: so `http://domain.com/2013/` is the root of the application? What web server are you using?

Comment: Note that `example.com/2013` is *not* a subdomain. `2013` is a folder. A subdomain would be: `2013.example.com`. Your absolute paths would work on a subdomain without any problems.

Comment: you are right, question edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or you can to try this code in you .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /2013/$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I need to put the .htaccess in the 2013 folder ?

Answer (score 2):

Setting the [base href](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_base.asp) should solve your problem.  The following should be placed in the `<head>` element of all your pages:

```
<base href="http://domain.com/2013/" />
```

Comment: yes http://domain.com/2013/ is the root of the application and hosted on dedicated server. with <base href="http://domain.com/2013/" />, the path used in javascript (for example, ajax calls) will be ok ?